# Number guessing game using TryParse

Tags: c#, tryparse

I´m having problems with getting my code to work while using TryParse to catch if the user where to input a string instead of a int. If I use it as it looks now I only get the base value of 0 if something other than an int is input. I want it to show an error message to the user.

Have tried messing around with a number of different ways of using TryParse but none of them has really been helpfull.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random r = new Random();
        int speltal = r.Next(1,21);
        bool play = false;
        int myNum;

        while (!play)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\tGuess a number between 1 and 20: ");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myNum);

            if (myNum < guessNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tThe number you have guessed is to low");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            if (myNum > guessNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tThe number you have guessed is to high");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            if (myNum == guessNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tCongratulations you guessed the right number!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

I want it show an error message to the user if they put in anything other than a int. It also have to include TryParse according to my teatcher

Comment: TryParse() returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails. Instead of ignoring the return value, do something like `if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myNum)) { /* report error */ } else { /* do whatever else */ }`. [They document these things](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8), you know.

Answer (score 4):

You're not capturing the `bool` output of `TryParse` so you have no idea if a non-numeric value was entered. Try something like this:

```
bool isValid;
do
{
     Console.Write("\n\tGuess a number between 1 and 20: ");
     isValid = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myNum);
     if(!isValid)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("\n\tInvalid input detected. Please try again.");
     }
} while(!isValid)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TryParse` method can only put integers in the passed variable (as it is of type `int`), so if the value passed to it can't be parsed into an integer, the default value of `int` (0) will be assigned to the variable.

The way `TryParse` tell you if it successfully parsed the number or not, is by returning a boolean indicator.

You can try this:

```
while (true)
{
    bool valid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myNum);
    if(valid)
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Input invalid. Please try again");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `bool` returned by `TryParse`. Something that looks like this:

Updated answer:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int guessNum = random.Next(1, 21);

            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guess the number between 1 and 21.");

                if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int input))
                {
                    if (input == guessNum)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"You guessed it right. The number is {input}");
                        if(ShouldContinue())
                        {
                            guessNum = random.Next();
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (input < guessNum)
                        Console.WriteLine("The number you guessed is smaller.");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("The number you guessed is bigger");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 21 as your guess");
                }
            }
        }

        static bool ShouldContinue()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Do you want to continue playing? (y/n)");
                string continueInput = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower();
                if (continueInput == "y")
                    return true;
                else if (continueInput == "n")
                    return false;
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!. Please choose 'y' or 'n'.");
            }
        }
```

Old answer:

```
while (true)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(inputInt, out int myNum))
    {
       // your logic goes here, too low/high or correct answer.   
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't show how to exit the infinite loop. Also this is basically a duplicate of Stanleys answer which was written 15 minutes earlier than this one.

Answer (score 0):

`TryParse` returns a Boolean which indicates if the input string was successfully parsed or not. Both of the answers above are correct on how to handle a invalid input but, here is a cleaner version which will also uphold the *rule*, `between 1 and 20`:

```
while (true)
{    
    Console.Write("\n\tGuess a number between 1 and 20: ");

    //Checks to see if the input was successfully parsed to a integer also, performs a Trim on the input as to remove any accidental white spaces that a user might have typed in, e.g. "1000 "
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().Trim(), out myNum))
    {
        //Checks to see if the parsed number is in the specified range
        if ((myNum > 0) && (myNum < 21))
        {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\tThe input number was out of the specified range.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tFailed to parse the input text.");
    }
    //Optional, makes the thread sleep so the user has the time to read the error message.
    Thread.Sleep(1500);

    //Optional, clears the console as to not create duplicates of the error message and the value of Console.Write
    Console.Clear();
}

// Continue here, if (myNum < guessNum) . . .
```